# Sending a file over a TCP server in a string

Tags: python-3.x

We need to send a pdf file over a TCP server in a string with the following format:

*command* *number* *date* *size* *file*

In the server, we're doing this:

```
l = f.read()
f.close()
user.sendall(("AQT " + "12345678 " + "16SET2015_12:00:00 " + str(size) + " " + l).encode('utf-8')
```

Our client looks like this:

```
            quiz = s.recv(buff_size)
            quiz_aux = quiz
            while(quiz_aux):
                quiz_aux = s.recv(buff_size)
                quiz += quiz_aux

            quiz = quiz.decode('utf-8')
            response = quiz.split(" ", 4)

            if response[0] == 'AQT':
                QID = eval(response[1])
                time = response[2]
                size = eval(response[3])

            file_name = topic + "QF" + "001" + ".pdf"
            f = open(file_name, "w")

            f.write(response[4])
            f.close()
            print("received file " + file_name)
```

We can't seem to get the encoding right, no matter what we try it doesn't work and it also doesn't seem to receive the entire file.

If somebody could help us we'd be truly grateful.

Comment: How big are your files? And how big is `buff_size`?

Comment: @cg909 right now we're testing with files with 60kb more or less. In the future, we will be transfering files with maybe 1/2mb. buff_size is 1024

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're most likely opening your file in ASCII instead of BINARY mode. Thats why you do not receive the complete file as you never read the complete file in the first place.

```
with open(file,'rb') as f:
    data = f.read() # reads the complete file.
```

Here're some flaws in your code:

- the decode('utf-8') magic is not required as you'll most likely want to transfer your data byte-by-byte.
- calling `eval` do parse an `int` is not secure, use `int()` instead.
- storing large files in variables or passing large files to a single `send/sendall` call is highly inefficient. This is also true for receiving large amounts of data.
- the protocol design is flawed. make sure your peer gets a hint about the message size pretty early.

Here's a working example of your code:

client:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import socket
import os

TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
TCP_PORT = 9999

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
with open(bigfile,'rb') as f:
    f.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
    size = f.tell()
    f.seek(0, os.SEEK_SET)
    x = f.read()
    s.sendall("AQT " + "12345678 " + "16SET2015_12:00:00 " + str(size) + " " + x)        
s.close()
```

server:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import socket


TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
TCP_PORT = 9999
buff_size = 1024*8
topic = "xyz"

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
s.listen(1)

print "ready"
conn, addr = s.accept()
print 'Connection address:', addr
quiz = conn.recv(buff_size)
quiz_aux = quiz
while(quiz_aux):
    quiz_aux = conn.recv(buff_size)
    quiz += quiz_aux

response = quiz.split(" ", 4)
print len(response)
if response[0] == 'AQT':
    QID = int(response[1])
    time = response[2]
    size = int(response[3])

file_name = topic + "QF" + "001" + ".txt"
f = open(file_name, "wb")
f.write(response[4])
f.close()
print("received file " + file_name)
conn.close()
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. our problem is that we can't make this work for pdf files, but it works for txt.

Comment: This code does a binary transfer and therefore works for plain ascii or binary data. I've tested it with 45MBytes of mp3, both sha-256 chksums matched, no corruption. Please make sure to read and write in binary mode (see `open(file,'rb')`) and re-run your test with this code snippet .